# Why does `width: fit-content` prevent long unbroken words from wrapping?

Tags: html, css

In the code snippet below, why does the inner content in Ex 1 overflow from the outer element, whereas in Ex 2, this does not occur? I'd expect both examples to either overflow or both to not overflow.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  width: fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
Ex 1

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    kasdhakjsdhaksjdhjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhghj 
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Ex 2
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd  
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Ex 3
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    asd asd asd
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`width: fit-content` forces the width of the container to, well, fit the content, up to the limit of `max-content`. Word breaks only occur if the content cannot fit within its container, but since the container is basically unbounded, the word doesn't wrap. You can see this if you set `overflow: hidden` on the outer container.

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content):

> The max-content sizing keyword represents the intrinsic maximum width of the content. For text content this means that the content will not wrap at all ***even if it causes overflows***.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  width: fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
Ex 1

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    kasdhakjsdhaksjdhjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhghj 
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Ex 2
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd  
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Ex 3
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    asd asd asd
  </div>
</div>
```

You can fix this by adding word-break as well, to force the words to break when they hit the edge of the container.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  width: fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 300px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
Ex 1

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    kasdhakjsdhaksjdhjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhghj 
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Ex 2
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd  
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Ex 3
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    asd asd asd
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still reading over your answer. I did notice that adding `word-break: break-word;` seems to cause neither to overflow. Is this expected per your understanding?

Comment: Yes, I just added that to my answer as well.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me why `word-break: break-word` causes the text to break, whereas `overflow-wrap: break-word` doesn't, but I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: Because word-break is based on whether the text exceeds the width of its content box, while overflow-wrap is based on whether the text causes overflow, which since the width is unbounded, it will never wrap on overflow (see the bolded part of the quote from Mozilla).

Comment: "Because word-break is based on whether the text exceeds the width of its content box": 

But isn't its content-box unbounded due to `width: fit-content`? Or is the "content box" the width of the container?

Comment: My best understanding is that word-break is based on whether or not the content will cause any parent container (up to the window, or itself) to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

an `inline-block` configuration can easily do it:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
Ex 1

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    kasdhakjsdhaksjdhjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhghj 
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Ex 2
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd  
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Ex 3
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    asd asd asd
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware of this, was specifically curious why `fit-content` wasn't working as I expected.